# Geometric interpretation of $(|a|^n+|b|^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: geometry

I'm looking for a geometric interpretation in $\Bbb{R}^2$ of $(|a|^n+|b|^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

For example, for $n=1$, $|a|+|b|$ can be interpreted as the sum of the lengths of two line segments. $(|a|^2+|b|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ can be interpreted as the distance between the origin and the point $(a,b)$. What about $n\geq 3$?

Answer (score 1):

$|a|+|b|=d$ is a square with the axes as diagonal, each semi-diagonal $=d$. 
$|a|^2+|b|^2=d^2$ is a circle of radius $d$.
For  $n$ increasing you depart progressively from the circle to move in the limit toward the  square $(\pm d, \pm d)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\big(\,|a|^n+|b|^n\,\big)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ can be thought of as the distance from point $\,(a,b)\,$ to the origin $\,(0,0)\,$ for different choices of the [metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Metric.html).

$\,n=1\,$ corresponds to the [taxicab (or Manhattan) metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm), $\,n=2\,$ to the [Euclidean metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), and $\,n\,$ in general to the metric induced by the  [p-norm $\,||\cdot||_p\,$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm). The fact that $\,||\cdot||_p\,$ is indeed a norm for $p \ge 1$ follows from the discrete case of [Minkovski's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality). The interpretation easily generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking for a geometric interpretation for any $n$, not whether or not it forms a metric. Making observations about the unit ball or maybe considering the bisectors and/or Voronoi regions would actually address the question.

Comment: @adfriedman `This doesn't answer the question.` Sorry, but I disagree. The OP indicated in the question that identifying the radical with the Euclidean distance to the origin in the case $n=2$ counts as a "*geometric interpretation*". My answer points out that the expression can *always* be thought of as the distance to the origin, only using a different metric.

Comment: @adfriedman  `Making observations about the unit ball` There is more info on the linked [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) than I could write into the post, including drawings of the [unit circle under different metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#/media/File:Vector_norms.svg). More of the same can be found [here](http://students.rockefeller.edu/fross/unit_circle/index.html) for example.